# Using Jasmine/Karma To Unit Test A Service Won't Inject A Copy Of The Service

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-services

**Warning, this is for a work project and as such, information is limited. If more information is necessary, ask and if I feel it's appropriate to add I will.**

I have spent about a day and a half with an issue where my unit test won't load a copy of the Service I am trying to test. The app.js (which houses the main app "CC" has the relevant section:

```
angular
  .module("CC", [
    "ui.router",
    "angularMoment",
    "focus-if",
    "ngCapsLock",
    "CC.AuthInterceptor",
    "CC.Filters",
    "CC.Body",
    "CC.Login",
    "CC.Courtyard",
    "CC.SocketService",
    "CC.HeaderNavbar",
    "CC.footerBar",
    "CC.AcademicHall",
    "CC.ResourceCenter",
    "CC.UserSettings",
    "CC.imageOnLoad",
    "CC.recommendedResources",
    "CC.Constants"
  ])
  .config(ConfigureCookies)
  .config(ConfigureResources)
  .config(ConfigureInterceptors)
  .config(ConfigureDefaultPage)
  .config(ConfigureHTML5Mode)
  .config(ConfigureRouter)
  .run(AuthRedirect);
```

The relevant modules (as I see it and this might be my issue) are CC.Constants (a module written by Grunt to contain constants containing relevant URLs) and CC.SocketService (the actual service being tested).

CC.Constants looks like this:

```
(function () { 
    "use strict";
    angular.module('CC.Constants', [])
        .constant('apiUrl', "<URL1>")
        .constant('socialUrl', "<URL2>"); 
}());
```

This is what I can show you from SocketService, I feel it's everything relevant, considering I am not at this point trying to explicitly test it, just get the testing set up.

```
(function() {
  "use strict";
  function SocketService($rootScope, $cookies, $log, $state, jwtHelper, moment, socialUrl) {
    var socket = {};
    socket.socket = {}; //This holds the socket connection after a specific function is run
    socket.data = {};
    socket.data.sortedMessages = [];
    socket.data.userChannels = [];
    socket.supportFunctions = {};
    socket.supportFunctions.sortPost = function(post) {
      for (var x = socket.data.userChannels.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
        if (post.courtyard_post_to === socket.data.userChannels[x].pk) {
          socket.data.userChannels[x].post_to_channel.push(post);
          return;
        }
      }
    };
    /* A bunch of other functions live here all under the socket object in one way or another */
    return socket;
  }
  SocketService.$inject = ["$rootScope", "$cookies", "$log", "$state", "jwtHelper", "moment", "socialUrl"];
  angular
    .module("CC.SocketService", [
      "ngCookies",
      "ui.router",
      "angularMoment",
      "angular-jwt"
    ])
    .factory("SocketService", SocketService);
})();
```

Below is the test as it is now.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    describe("ConnectedCampus.SocketService", function () {
        var $cookies,
            $state,
            Socket;
        var channel1 = {an imitation channel goes here};
        var channel2 = {an imitation channel goes here};
        var channel3 = {an imitation channel goes here};
        var postToChannel1 = {an imitation post goes here};

        beforeEach(function (){
            $cookies = jasmine.createSpyObj("$cookies", ["get", "put"]);
            $cookies.get.and.returnValue("<valid Login Token Goes Here>");
            $state = jasmine.createSpyObj("$state", ["go"]);
            module("CC");
            module("CC.SocketService");
            module(function ($provide) {
                $provide.value("$cookies", $cookies);
                $provide.value("$state", $state);
                $provide.constant("socialUrl", "fakeAddress");
            });
            inject(function (SocketService) {
                Socket = SocketService;
            })
        });
        describe("Support Functions", function () {
            it("socket.supportFunctions.sortPost should push a new post into the channel's posts array.", function (done) {
                console.log("Socket");
                console.log(Socket);//this logs "undefined"
                Socket.data.userChannels = [channel1, channel2, channel3];
                Socket.supportFunctions.sortPost(postToChannel1);
                expect(Socket.data.userChannels[0].post_to_channel).toContain(postToChannel1);
                done();
            })
        });
    });
}());
```

Here's the stacktrace:

```
SocketService@<path to app>/app/socket/socket.js:320:25 //the file is only 208 lines long
invoke@<path to app>/app/libs/angular/angular.js:4535:22
enforcedReturnValue@<path to app>/app/libs/angular/angular.js:4387:43
invoke@<path to app>/app/libs/angular/angular.js:4535:22
<path to app>/app/libs/angular/angular.js:4352:43
getService@<path to app>/app/libs/angular/angular.js:4494:46
invoke@<path to app>/app/libs/angular/angular.js:4526:23
workFn@<path to app>/app/libs/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2517:26
inject@<path to app>/app/libs/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2489:41
<path to app>/app/socket/socket_test.js:321:19
<path to app>/app/login/login_test.js:49:17 //I don't know why these are here, login tests are passing
<path to app>/app/login/login_test.js:43:17 //I don't know why these are here, login tests are passing
<path to app>/app/courtyard/courtyard_test.js:474:21
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Socket.data') in <path to app>/app/socket/socket_test.js (line 337) //Line 337 is the line 'Socket.data.userChannels = [channel1, channel2, channel3];'
/home/anton/git/connected_campus-ng/app/socket/socket_test.js:337:23
<path to app>/app/login/login_test.js:49:17 //I don't know why these are here, login tests are passing
<path to app>/app/login/login_test.js:43:17 //I don't know why these are here, login tests are passing
<path to app>/app/courtyard/courtyard_test.js:474:21 //I don't know why these are here, courtyard tests are passing
```

And here's my files seen by Karma via grunt:

```
files: [
    "app/libs/angular/angular.js",
    "app/libs/moment/moment.min.js",
    "app/libs/**/*.js",
    "app/app.js",
    "app/constants.js",
    "app/**/*.js"//SocketService lives in 'app/socket/socket.js'
],
```

A few things I've tried:

1. I have tried underscore notation
2. I have tried the beforeEach being inside the inner describe
3. I have tried separating the beforeEach into multiple beforeEach's in the (assumed) correct order
4. I have tried inline injection for the individual test
5. I've tried using $injector.get() and then injecting every requirement
6. I have tried $injector.get("SocketService")

Here are my version numbers for dependencies (pulled from bower and package).

BOWER:

```
"angular": "1.4.9",
"angular-cookies": "1.4.9",
"angular-resource": "1.4.9",
"angular-animate": "1.4.9",
"angular-ui-router": "0.2.18",
"ng-file-upload-shim": "12.0.1",
"ng-file-upload": "12.0.1",
"bootstrap":"3.3.6",
"angular-loader": "1.4.9",
"angular-mocks": "1.4.9",
"angular-bootstrap": "1.1.2",
"fontawesome": "4.5.0",
"moment": "2.12.0",
"angular-moment": "1.0.0-beta.5",
"socket.io-client": "1.4.6",
"angular-jwt": "0.0.9",
"ng-focus-if": "1.0.5",
"ng-caps-lock": "1.0.2",
"animate.css": "3.5.1",
"angular-media-queries": "0.5.1"
```

PACKAGE:

```
"bower": "1.7.9",
"bower-installer": "1.2.0",
"grunt": "1.0.1",
"grunt-contrib-concat": "1.0.1",
"grunt-contrib-cssmin": "1.0.1",
"grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "1.4.0",
"grunt-contrib-jshint": "1.0.0",
"grunt-contrib-sass": "1.0.0",
"grunt-contrib-watch": "1.0.0",
"grunt-githooks": "0.6.0",
"grunt-karma": "1.0.0",
"grunt-ng-annotate": "2.0.2",
"grunt-ng-constant": "2.0.1",
"http-server": "0.9.0",
"jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
"jshint-stylish": "2.2.0",
"karma": "0.13.22",
"karma-coverage": "1.0.0",
"karma-ie-launcher": "1.0.0",
"karma-jasmine": "1.0.2",
"karma-junit-reporter": "1.0.0",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.0",
"karma-safari-launcher": "1.0.0",
"phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.7",
"protractor": "3.3.0",
"shelljs": "0.7.0"
```

Absolutely any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't understand this, I've tested services before, and the actual Socket code works. Again, if you need more information feel free to ask but I might not be able to give it to you.

Comment: should the socket service js include come before app.js or something in the karma conf?  If nothing else, it needs to come before the test js, right?  Without filenames that have paths, it's hard to say if the karma conf is including things in the right order - but I know I've had similar issues with missing services and had it come down to that.

Comment: It works for all my other tests, there's about 30 other tests for other controllers and services. It's meant to load angular (before any angular modules), moment (so it loads before the angularMoment module), then all external modules, then the apps main module, then constants, finally all other application modules. Tests sit in the folder with the item they test, named the same with '_test.js' appended. So socket.js and socket_test.js live in the folder socket in the folder app. I will try and switch it up to see if that makes a difference though and I'll get back to you.

Comment: When I switch it up so that the load order is 
                    `files: [
                        "app/libs/angular/angular.js",
                        "app/libs/moment/moment.min.js",
                        "app/libs/**/*.js",
                        "app/constants.js",
                        "app/**/*.js",
                        "app/app.js"

                    ],`
It still doesn't work. But nothing new breaks.

EDIT: I also tried explicitly adding the socket.js to the files list, still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue, and it lies outside of what I revealed. I am not sure *why* my changes worked, but in my case it did, and in case anyone has the same issue, I want to put my fix out there.

The SocketService is a service that wraps a Socket.IO socket in personal logic and brings the javascript global io.connect() and other io/socket functionality into the angular ecosystem. I had it so that the actual connection was created on calling an event `socket.createConnection()` which worked in the actual code, but for some reason doesn't work in testing. I made the connection an event that fires every time you initialize the service aka `socket.socket = io.connect(socialUrl)` near the top of the file and this seemed to fix it. So now the top of the file looks like:

```
function SocketService($rootScope, $cookies, $log, $state, jwtHelper, moment, socialUrl) {
    /* The object to be returned by the service, includes:
     * .data(actual data),
     * .supportFunctions(functions to sort and place data),
     * .callbackFunctions(callbacks to call on 'on' events
     * .socket which contains the actual socket connection */
    var socket = {};
    /* Object to hold socket connection */
    socket.socket = io.connect(socialUrl); //This is the important change
    /* Holds all the data gathered so far by the socket */
    socket.data = {};
    /* Holds all the sorted messages */
    socket.data.sortedMessages = [];
    /* Holds all the channels the user is a member of */
    socket.data.userChannels = [];
    /* Object holding all the support functions necessary for the data to be manipulated as expected */
    socket.supportFunctions = {};
```

This is now working with the outer describe containing an underscore notated declaration. As seen below, this test now passes meaning the change worked:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    describe("ConnectedCampus.SocketService", function () {
        /* jshint unused: false */
        var $rootScope,
            $cookies,
            $log,
            $state,
            jwtHelper,
            moment,
            SocketService;
        var channel1 = <imitation channel object>;
        var channel2 = <imitation channel object>;
        var channel3 = <imitation channel object>;
        var postToChannel1 = <imitation post to 1st channel>;

        beforeEach(function (){
            $cookies = jasmine.createSpyObj("$cookies", ["get", "put"]);
            $cookies.get.and.returnValue("<valid auth token>");
            $state = jasmine.createSpyObj("$state", ["go"]);
            module("angularMoment");
            module("angular-jwt");
            module("ConnectedCampus.Constants");
            module("ConnectedCampus.SocketService");
            module(function ($provide) {
                $provide.value("$cookies", $cookies);
                $provide.value("$state", $state);
                $provide.constant("socialUrl", "Yellow");
            });
            inject(function (_$rootScope_, _$log_, _jwtHelper_, _moment_, _SocketService_) {
                $rootScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
                $log = _$log_;
                jwtHelper = _jwtHelper_;
                moment = _moment_;
                SocketService = _SocketService_;
            })
        });

        describe("Support Functions", function () {


            it("socket.supportFunctions.sortPost should push a new post into the channel's posts array.", function (done) {
                SocketService.data.userChannels = [channel1, channel2, channel3];
                SocketService.supportFunctions.sortPost(postToChannel1);
                expect(SocketService.data.userChannels[0].post_to_channel).toContain(postToChannel1);
                done();
            })
        });
    });
}());
```

Again, I am not sure *why* this worked, and I don't want to throw around opinions, but if you ever have a similar issue, this *might* be the solution.